# Question about length of a parametrized curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Firstly, the exercise wants me to calculate the length of a parametrized curve.
The curve is defined by the equations: 
$x=a\sin^{3}\left(t\right)$ and $y=a\cos^{3}t$

**My solution:**

If we name $f\left(t\right)$ the parametrization of the curve

Since I don't get any bounds for "$t$" then I suppose that it goes from $0$ to $w$

Then the length of the curve is $${\int_{0}^{w}}\left\Vert f'\left(t\right)\right\Vert ={\int_{0}^{w}}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^{2}}dt.$$ I considered the Euclidean norm.

After considering that, I calculated all the requirements for the integral:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=3\,a\,\sin^{2}\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)\Rightarrow\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{2}=9\,a^{2}\,\sin^{4}\left(t\right)\,\cos^{2}\left(t\right)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3\,a\,\cos^{2}\left(t\right)\sin\left(t\right)\Rightarrow\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^{2}=9a^{2}\cos^{4}\left(t\right)\sin^{2}\left(t\right)$$

So the solution I get is \begin{align*}&{\int_{0}^{w}}\sqrt{9\,a^{2}\,\sin^{4}\left(t\right)\,\cos^{2}\left(t\right)+9a^{2}\cos^{4}\left(t\right)\sin^{2}\left(t\right)}dt\\
 &={\int_{0}^{w}}\sqrt{9\,a^{2}\,\sin^{2}\left(t\right)\cos^{2}\left(t\right)\left(\sin^{2}\left(t\right)+\cos^{2}\left(t\right)\right)}dt\\
&=3a{\int_{0}^{w}}\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)dt\\
&= \dfrac{3a}{2} \sin^2 w\\
\end{align*}

My questions are:

-Have I done something wrong? Because the length is growing and decreasing because of the cosine.

-Should I get the maximum of the function that I get as solution?

-Why does it decreases?

Comment: A few things regarding the typesetting: if you put a backslash in front of $sin$, as in `\sin(x)`, it renders as $\sin(x)$. Further, the lower bound of your integral should be $0$, not $o$, since you haven't defined $o$.

Comment: As for the length, this is a closed curve (each component is periodic, so it will eventually repeat itself). In this case, the bounds don't need to be provided since you can just determine when the curve will start repeating itself.

Comment: @Clayton thanks, I have to improve my typing in general, talking about my exercise, so is from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: That is correct. So these will be your bounds

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: $\sqrt{a^2}  = |a|$. And you can't turn a definite integral into an antiderivative ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint*:

Because of the symmetries of the curve, it is enough to compute the integral from $0$ to $\frac\pi4$, and multiply the result by $8$. On this interval, sine and cosine are nonnegative.

Comment: The question is when $w= 2\pi$ why does the arc still remain at $3a/2?$

Answer (score 1):

This is an envelope of a sliding ladder with ends on $(x,y)$ axes.

It has four real cusps, four complex cusps and two complex double points.

The Astroid can be graphed in the four quadrants and is periodic in each quadrant. Each quadrant envelope length is $\dfrac{3a}{2}$ should be multiplied by the number of quadrants the ladder turns.

A real variable trig interpretation into the complex variable situation after repeated crossing cusps is seen as a *Catastrophe*, as real interpretation *will just not succeed.*

Catastrophe theory originated with the work of the French mathematician René Thom in the 1960s, and became very popular due to the efforts of Christopher Zeeman in the 1970s.

Their theory is full of such examples (like swallow tail, the 4:1 ratio of rolling radii generating the hypo-cycloid you mention and the like) with a physically convincing interpretation of dynamics going through all cusps.

The fractional indices are often a common feature. In the Astroid case you brought in we have

$$ x^{\frac23} +y^{\frac23}= a^{\frac23} $$

EDIT1:

The same happens for a common cycloid of rolling circle radius $a$ that has arc length $8a.$